# Simple Imputer cannot impute by column

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have X_train that shapes (14599, 13), i'm trying to impute NaN with column's median but somehow it imputes with row resulting error because in a row there are date, and other than integer values. I already lookup if SimpleImputer has axis parameter but could not find that it exists. How to solve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


plt.close('all')
avo_sales = pd.read_csv('avocados.csv')
avo_sales.rename(columns = {'4046':'small PLU sold',
                            '4225':'large PLU sold',
                            '4770':'xlarge PLU sold'},
                 inplace= True)
avo_sales.columns = avo_sales.columns.str.replace(' ','')

plt.scatter(avo_sales.Date,avo_sales.TotalBags)

x = np.array(avo_sales.drop(['TotalBags'],1))
y = np.array(avo_sales.TotalBags)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

imp = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
X_train = imp.fit_transform(X_train)
```

the output

````
ValueError: Cannot use median strategy with non-numeric data:
could not convert string to float: '12/31/2017'
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's trying to impute across rows; rather, it's trying to impute in the dates column.  You may want to use ColumnTransformer to select which columns to impute.